# App performance different on iPod touch than iPhone 4s

Tags: iphone, ipod-touch

App performance when testing on iPhone is very good but when testing same app on iPod touch performance is not good fonts looks smaller and modalviewcontroller transition speed is very fast. Action sheet button performance is very slow.

Any idea how to fix this performance issue when testing same app on iPod touch.

Comment: it would probably be a good idea to run the activity monitor instrument on your device to look at the system resource utilization. beyond that, if you are comparing iphone 4s with the 4th Gen ipod, there shouldnt be a lot of difference in performance

Comment: i guess it is third generation iPod model mc086ll 8 gb software ver 4.2.1

Comment: well.. performance optimization is a vast topic and cant help much without more information as to what the app is and where exactly it is slow. i have never seen smaller fonts though. try with another ipod of the same generation. however point to note is that its a 620 mhz device, and its expected.

Answer (score 0):

That's normal because the difference in the hardware of each device.